# Receiving "Java has been detached" already error when trying to run application

Tags: java, macos

I have been trying to use a Java application that I found on GitHub to convert HTML5/ImpressJS slide decks to PDF. Yesterday, the app was "working" in the sense that it could do PDF conversions as long as the presentations had 7 slides or less. Today it simply crashes when I try to execute.

I have tried:

- Reinstalling Java JDK (8u31)
- Rebuilding the application
- Restarting my laptop (running Mac OS X 10.10, for reference)

I have also tried Googling for the error, or parts of it, without success. The error in full is:

```
Exception in Application start method
Java has been detached already, but someone is still trying to use it at -[GlassRunnable run]:/HUDSON/workspace/8u31/label/macosx-universal-30/rt/modules/graphics/src/main/native-glass/mac/GlassApplication.m:92
Java has been detached already, but someone is still trying to use it at -[GlassRunnable dealloc]:/HUDSON/workspace/8u31/label/macosx-universal-30/rt/modules/graphics/src/main/native-glass/mac/GlassApplication.m:106
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$49/1099983479.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find a profile named 'impressj
    at me.champeau.deck2pdf.ProfileLoader.loadProfile(ProfileLoader.java:59)
    at me.champeau.deck2pdf.Main.start(Main.java:84)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$52/1021330729.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/128893786.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/2015866367.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1108411398.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application me.champeau.deck2pdf.Main
```

It's worth noting that some of the search results indicated that this is an Eclipse error, but I don't even have Eclipse installed since I am not a Java developer by trade. I am not sure if this would impact the application since it was running prior to this morning. The only notable event this morning was that it started to convert a deck, but crashed on the second or third slide. I have not been able to "get it back" since, despite the above troubleshooting.

Comment: I don't think that your problem iare the 'detached' messages, I see that sporadically when shutting down my JavaFX application by closing the (only) window it has. Both on OS X and on windows. This seems to happen when a JavaFX application shuts down.
Your problem is the reason for the shutdown, and that is indicated by the message "Cannot find a profile named 'impressj".
I don't know Impress, so I can't tell you what exactly is missing, but it seems you somehow have to provide some kind of profile.
I hope this helps you in searching the real cause.

Comment: I see a similar result on the command-line with JavaFX 16 after inadvertantly throwing `MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED`.